# Copy from one table with auto increment column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I want to copy the data from one table1 into table2. table1 does not have one of the columns that exists in table2 but it needs to be unique for my purpose.

My code is this so far:

```
set @uidfield=1000;

insert into table2 (column1, colulmn2, column3) 
    select column1, column2, (@uidfield := @uidfield+1) 
    from table1
```

This will copy about 6000 records, I don't have a good way to test my SQL statement, and I want to make sure its somewhat right before I send it to my SR analyst.

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Where did you find `:=` syntax? That does not look like SQL Server. Are you trying to create a unique sequence number for each row from `table1`? Try `insert dbo.table1(...) SELECT column1, column2, @uidfield + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM dbo.table1;`

Comment: SQL Server2012, i just found the := on google somewhere, i didnt think it was correct, ill try the @uidfield + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) and see what my SR thinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
insert into table2 (column1, colulmn2, column3) 
    select column1, column2, 
           1000 + row_number() over (order by (select null))
    from table1;
```

This would be the SQL Server equivalent of your syntax, if I interpret your syntax as MySQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, i just wanted to have the syntax correct before i sent it to my Sr analyst, ive never used the row number function and i dont have a place to test it really so i wanted to make sure it was correct.